Replicating IF ANY conditional logic or a SUMIF Equivalent in PeopleSoft Query
Setting up an expression with conditional logic to determine the type of requisition within our business logic. Some requisitions can have multiple REQ_LINE.LN_TYPE (e.g. Req Line 1 = CAT & Req Line 2 = SR). In this case for certain requisition types, the requisition should be treated as SR.
I was thinking that I could assign each req line a number based on the line type (SR = 1 and all other types = 0) then sum the lines of a single requisition. If the summed value > 0 then the output would be the req type for SR.
If I was using excel, I could do a SUMIF and then an IF statement to determine a single outcome for each requisition.
Tried with this as an expression:
SUM (CASE WHEN REQ_LINE.LN_TYPE = 'SR'
THEN 1
ELSE 0
GROUP BY (REQ_HDR.BUSINESS_UNIT, REQ_HDR.REQ_ID))
Receiving an error:  Code=905, Message=ORA-00905: missing keyword (50,380)
Any insight on how to approach this would be helpful!

It looks like you are on the right track but since the error says you are missing key words, we can start there. From doing some looking around, it looks like the case statement itself needs the END keyword after the "else 0".
Something along the lines of
SELECT
SUM (CASE WHEN REQ_LINE.LN_TYPE = 'SR' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM REQ_LINE, REQ_HDR
GROUP BY REQ_HDR.BUSINESS_UNIT, REQ_HDR.REQ_ID

I found this other question that might be able to assist as well:
How sum with case conditional statement works in sql
